# Check if Google Nearby is already allowed

Tags: android, google-nearby

Is there some way to verify if the Google Nearby API is already authorized or not?
The method `enableAutoManage()` do everything atomatically, so, it doesn't help, I want to use the `publish()` and `subscribe()` only if I already have the permission, otherwise, do nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have permission, GoogleApiClient.connect() will fail.

See "Handle errors" in the following link on how to handle that error and ask for user permission or just fail.

See the following for more details
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/user-consent

Comment: That's right! there's a class listing the possible status codes and `NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.APP_NOT_OPTED_IN` is the error for my question. Thank you!